# spotify api axios react put request 403 error

Tags: reactjs, axios, spotify

When I click on the button, I have to save the track to my library
But I am getting a 403 error.
**Everything is fine with the token, all other 'get' requests work. Only "put" doesn't work**

Official documentation - https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/save-tracks-user

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBCNx.png)

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const requestWithToken = (TYPE, URL, ACCESS_TOKEN, DATA) => {
  const request = async () => {
    let result;
    let options = {
      url: URL,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
      method: TYPE,
      data: DATA,
    };
    try {
      result = await axios(options);
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
    return result;
  };
  return request();
};
```

```
const handleFollow = async () => {
     try{
      const response = await requestWithToken(
       'PUT',
       `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/albums?ids=4Cd2EftimaltmI0irA1dCX`,
        accessToken,
      );
     } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
return (
<button onClick={() => {
        handleFollow();
=}}>saved track</button>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you pass the ids in the url (as Query) request while in the documentation it is mentioned that the ids must be in body,
So you request should be like this

```
    const handleFollow = async () => {
     try{
      const response = await requestWithToken(
       'PUT',
       'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks',
        accessToken,
        {
          'ids': [
             '4Cd2EftimaltmI0irA1dCX'
          ]
        }
      );
     } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

You can also check your token if it has the full access this [link](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-several-tracks/?market=&ids=) and then **Get token** button [image]

Verify the new token by running the code below in your terminal

```
 curl --request PUT \
      --url https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks \
      --header 'Authorization: Bearer NEW_TOKEN' \
      --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      --data '{
      "ids": [
        "4Cd2EftimaltmI0irA1dCX"
      ]
    }'
```

Comment: Nothing has changed @Layed Mazen

Comment: Can you check this request in your terminal if it works 

curl --request PUT \
  --url https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer  YOUR TOKEN HERE' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "ids": [
    "4Cd2EftimaltmI0irA1dCX"
  ]
}'

Comment: "error": {
        "status": 403,
        "message": "Forbidden."
    } @Layed Mazen

Comment: hmm I understand, your token does not have full access.
Can you try to generate a token from this link https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-several-tracks/?market=&ids= 
and try the request with the new token

Comment: i updated the response above